# How can I use ng-if to check if the string contains others substrings?

Tags: angularjs

First, I want to use ng-if to check if the string contains others substring "#teamA" or "#teamB" like:

```
<ion-item ng-if="msg.indexOf("#teamA") > -1" class="teamA">            
    {{msg}}
</ion-item>
<ion-item ng-if="msg.indexOf("#teamB") > -1" class="teamB">            
    {{msg}}
</ion-item>
```

This code is not working.
Secondly, I want each {{msg}} to have different assigned class (teamA and teamB). Am I on the right way to do that (if my ng-if works)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per you requirement, what you need to use actually is `ngClass`

```
ng-class="{'teamA': msg.indexOf('#teamA') > -1, 'teamB': msg.indexOf('#teamB') > -1}"
```

Then you only need one element

```
<ion-item ng-class="see above...">            
{{msg}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks. Does it work with any javascript expression in ng-class?

Comment: Yes all javascript expression can work here but what you need to keep in mind is all objects in this expression should be able to access in current scope or they are globally defined.

Answer (score 5):

You have double quotes inside of a double quote. Your code works just fine.

```
<div ng-if="msg.indexOf('#teamA') > -1" class="teamA">
    {{ msg }}
</div>
<div ng-if="msg.indexOf('#teamB') > -1" class="teamB">
    {{ msg }}
</div>
```